# How do I access User Defined Fields from the Profiles API using Directory API

Tags: google-directory-api, google-profiles-api

We have an application that manages User Accounts in Google.  All customers considered we are managing roughly 1 million accounts.

We have already built and deployed a Directory API based replacement for our Provisioning API based solution.  One of the features available in Profiles API that doesn't migrate well to Directory API is User Defined fields.

Using our old solution on Profiles API a customer could add user defined fields to a UserEntry or ContactEntry object and those fields would show up in the Directory view for those objects.

Using Directory API I believe our replacement for User Defined Fields is using Schema and SchemaFieldSpec objects.

In that use case, user defined fields are separated into namespaces by the schema name.
So, we have found that

(1) our solution has no access to the fields created by the Profiles    API; and 
   (2) new user defined fields being set by Directory API are not visible in the Directory U/I.

Is there a plan to line those two features up?  Am I missing something in making those fields visible?

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this feature gap and we're working on a solution. Follow this issue for updates:

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3815